# How to get the path of a file that is not in the current working directory

Tags: java, io, filepath

I have a question. My working directory is C:\Users\Damien\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ .The file I want to access is in C:\Users\Damien\My Pictures\body.jpg. I have been trying to no avail to get the path of that file from Java. How do I go about it? I tried to use this

```
File f = new File("..\\My Pictures\\body.jpg");
    try {
        System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("file cannot be found");
    }
```

but it prints this
C:\Users\Damien\Documents\NetBeansProjects\My Pictures\body.jpg. Thanks.

Comment: f.getAbsolutePath()   ??

Comment: I think that you need another ..\\ like this: ("..\\..\\My Pictures\\body.jpg");

Comment: @peggy Thanks.Tried f.getAbsolutePath(). Same as answer as above.

Answer (score 0):

It really is prudent to either use absolute paths in this scenario, or better still, move the relevant files to your project resource folder.

That being said, if you really need the relative path of a certain file, you can use the [`relativize(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) method.

For a given path `p`, and another path `q`, this will construct a relative path between `p` and `q`.

In your case, `p` should be `C:\Users\Damien\Documents\NetBeansProjects`, and `q` should be `C:\Users\Damien\My Pictures\body.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks. What does relativize do? Does it symbolically link them? Can you show me with an example code?

Comment: @corax : What do you mean by a symbolic link in Java? It creates a `Path` object, as defined in the NIO library. There are literally many dozens of tutorials on how to use the NIO library. [This one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/path.html#creating-a-relative-path) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the absolute path:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Damien\\My Pictures\\body.jpg");
```

Comment: i think the OP wants to use a relative path with respect to the current directory.

Comment: OP said "I have been trying to no avail to get the path of that file from Java." No mention of relative paths. I gave an answer to his problem using absolute paths.

Comment: If an answer helps the asker, they accept it. Upvotes/downvotes are for the answer being useful or not useful. I'm not sure if it helps the original asker.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. But the point is that I want to encapsulate it in a function where I pass the name of the file in a string and the system generates the absolute path of the file so I can further manipulate it